# How to add new rows into a jTable from database while button click without clearing existing rows

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans-8

How to add new rows into a jTable from database while button click without clearing existing rows in jTable?

I tried lot of ways. But no success. Help

```
String SQL = "SELECT name,price FROM items WHERE ID = ' "+jTextField1.getText()+" ' ";
pst = Conn.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
jTable1.setModel(DbUnits.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

*Edit:-*
With the help of all answers i change the code into below code, But
OK . But here i get a error in **DefaultTableModel**

```
String sql = "SELECT name,price FROM items WHERE ID = '"+jtxt1.getText()+"'";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTabelModel(new String[]{"Name","Price"},0);
        Vector row = new Vector();
        while(rs.next())
        {
        String d = rs.getString("name");
        String e = rs.getString("price");
        row.add(new Object[]{d,e});

        model.addRow(row);}
```

**New Code**

```
String sql = "SELECT name,price FROM items WHERE ID = '"+jtxt1.getText()+"'";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
Vector row = new Vector();
row.add(rs);
model.addRow(row);
```

**Newest Code**

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData;
public void metaData() throws SQLException {
        this.metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        }
String sql = "SELECT name,price FROM items WHERE ID = '"+jtxt1.getText()+"'";
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs=pst.executeQuery();

            int columnCount = metaData.getColumnCount();
            Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<String>();

            for (int column = 1; column <= columnCount; column++) {
                columnNames.add(metaData.getColumnName(column));
                System.out.println("ColumnNames "+columnNames );
            }

            DefaultTableModel datamodel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
            jTable1.setModel(datamodel);

            while (rs.next()) {
                Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>();
                for (int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= columnCount; columnIndex++) {
                vector.add(rs.getString(columnIndex)); 
                }
                datamodel.addRow(vector);
            }
```

**But here i get a NullpointException error ! And how do i select jTable1 as the table in above code ?

Comment: 1) Why are you adding an Array to the Vector? I sure hope this is NOT code you found in an accepted answer in the forum. I would like to see the link were you found this code? You should just be adding the name and price directly to the Vector. 2) `I get an error in DefaultTableModel` - we are not mind readers, we don't know what the error is. Again, did you search the forum for the error message? 3) why are you creating a new DefaultTableModel. Your question is about adding new rows to the existing table model. So you only need a reference to the model so you can use the addRow(...) method.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for disturbing. :\  New code what is the error ?

Comment: I give up you haven't listened to any advice given. 1) you still haven't posted the error message. 2) you have been told you need to loop through the ResultSet and add one row of data at a time. Your first edit has the loop, the second edit doesn't. 3) you have bee told to add the "name"  and "price" to the Vector (not the ResultSet).  4) you have been told to search the forum for examples. There are plenty of example that show how to add data to a Vector. It would appear you also need to buy a programming text book. This is basic Java that you should know before doing database programming.

Comment: Error - not showing anything in the jTable,

Comment: But it works as i wanted!(Can add row by row) (But nothing showing in that rows.

Comment: I search all over the forum. But i didn't found any answer. I listened to your advised @camickr

Comment: For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21380575/jtable-only-displaying-1-row/21380775#21380775. All you need is the "while loop". It adds each column of data from the ResultSet to a Vector. Then it just adds the Vector to the DefaultTableModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process each row of data from the ResultSet and create a Vector and [use this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow(java.util.Vector)) to insert the data into the table model. You are creating new table model and setting it on the table, the old model with the data is lost.

After below request in comment:

This is one way to do it.

```
Vector<Vector<String>> data=new Vector<>();
//Fill this Vector above with the initial data

Vector<String> columns=new Vector<String>();
//Fill this with column names

DefaultTableModel tableModel=new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
JTable table=new JTable(tableModel);
//Display the table as you like

... //Query the database and get the ResultSet (let's call it rs)

while(rs.next){

  Vector<String> newRow=new Vector<>();

  //Get the data from the resultset and fill this new row

  tableModel.addRow(newRow);

}//while closing
```

Comment: Pls. Explain it ! Step by step.

Comment: OK Thanks. But I'm not good at Java. So pls can you modify my code into correct code. Please!

Comment: What is your objective here, is it some kind of college project?

Comment: I'm trying to develop a POS system(Billing, Inventory..) .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335309/data-retrieving-from-a-database-to-a-table-by-clicking-a-button

Comment: So in which line I should add the sql query?? @Ironluca