# Data retrieving from a database to a table by clicking a button

Tags: java, mysql, database, swing

I want to make a POS system.
I enter a item number(in jTextField) and press button. 
Then according to the item number its name and price should display in the jTable(relevant record to the item number in the database)

Then I enter another number and press button. And it also should display in the jTable without clearing existing data (as a new row)

```
String SQL = "SELECT name,price FROM items WHERE ID = ' "+jTextField1.getText()+" ' ";
pst = Conn.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = pst.executeQuery();
jTable1.setModel(DbUnits.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

Please help me to build this.
Note : I have already built this program. I know this isn't a freelance site !
I'm asking for a help for add new rows with data without clearing existing data.

Comment: [Creaing a GUI with Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html), [JDBC Basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) should help you get started.  When you have a specific question or issue which you can't seem to solve, the please, don't hesitate to post A question, detailing what you want, what you have tried and in what ways it's not working

Comment: What have you tried? This is not a freelancing site, where your project is solved by others.

Comment: I searched everywhere but I couldn't find any answer for my question. That's why I posted on stack overflow.com !

Comment: I have coded this program. But I couldn't get the ideal

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Code added! Pls help

Comment: *"Code added!"* An MCVE as suggested by @ErwinBolwidt is not uncompilable code snippets. Read the document carefully before making further edits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it also should display in the jTable without clearing existing data (as a new row)

Well then you can't use the `setModel(...)` method since that will replace all the existing data with the new data.

And you can't use the `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(...)` method since that will return new TableModel.

Instead you will need to read the data from the `ResultSet` one row at a time. As you read each row you will then you can use the `addRow(...)` method of the `DefaultTableModel` to add each new row of data to the existing model.

Comment: So @camickr can you please show me that (modifying my code) I'm not good at java.

Comment: @UdithaKanishka, We are not here to do your work for you. You won't improve if you don't write your own code or at least even learn how to find example code that does mostly what you want. Then you customize the code for your exact requirement. This is learning by example. Search the forum for examples. I highlighted a few keywords you might use in a search.

Comment: Ok Thanks.   @camickr

Answer (score 0):

I used this code instead of above code. But it shows **javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel@57168dd4** in the jTable.

```
String sql = "SELECT name,price FROM items WHERE ID = '"+jtxt1.getText()+"'";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();
    DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
    Vector row = new Vector();
    row.add(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    model.addRow(row);
```

Help !!

Comment: This does NOT look like the code found in your previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46321203/how-to-add-new-rows-into-a-jtable-from-database-while-button-click-without-clear. You have been given the basic structure of the code to loop through each row of data in the ResultSet. All you need to do is modify the code to add data to the newRow Vector. So you need to read the ResultSet API to find out how to get data for each column. Or, you could look at the source code of DbUtils. Or you could search the forum like I suggested.